# Network between MacOS 10.13.5 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, wireless-networking, home-networking

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 desktop with 11TB of storage and a MacBook Pro with a 250GB hard drive. I'd like to set up a network where the Ubuntu desktop can be recognized by the MacBook Pro as an external USB Harddrive (Ideally this would be two way). I assume this is pretty simple, but the solutions I've tried so far require me to take up space on the physical hard drive of the mac to share files.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Why not set up traditional file share on the Ubuntu machine?  "Recognized by the MacBook Pro as an external USB Harddrive" is probably not possible.  It would help if you listed the solutions you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu, like almost all GNU/Linux distros, contains Samba, which is an open source implementation of Microsoft Windows' SMB file service protocol. macOS has an SMB client (and server for that matter) built in, and in fact SMB has become the preferred file sharing protocol of macOS (Apple has deprecated their own AFP, and Unix's NFS, file sharing protocols).

So connect the two machines via Gigabit Ethernet, fire up Samba on Ubuntu if you haven't already, and have your Mac mount your Ubuntu machine's hard drive via SMB.

Comment: Not enough detail. I have samba installed & running on my Debian server, that and my Mac are on the same network, and I can't connect.